# Is there any way to apply click function only on mobile screen in angular

Tags: angular

```
<li> <a routerLink="../pages/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="hide()">
      <span class='md:ml-3 whitespace-no-wrap block md:inline-block text-sm md:text-lg'>Dashboard</span> 
    </a>
  </li>
```

I want to apply the click function only on devices with max-width:600px.
Is there any way we can do this?

Comment: Using what specifically? It's possible in `css` also in `Angular`

Comment: Just check the screen width in the click handler, or write a directive

Comment: @bryan60 Thanks checked screen width. It helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In your `.ts`

```
public innerWidth: any;
isDisabled: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if (this.innerWidth < 600) {
       this.isDisabled = false;
    } else {
       this.isDisabled = true;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="isDisabled">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could utilise Angular Material [Layout package](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) it's pretty convenient and comes up with loads of utility

```
import {BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints} from '@angular/cdk/layout';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

public isSmallScreen:boolean;
  constructor(public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
    const layoutChanges = breakpointObserver.observe("(max-width: 599px)");

    layoutChanges.subscribe(result => {
      this.smallScreen= result.matches
    });
  }
}
```

```
hide(){
if(!this.smallScreen){
   Your Logic//
  }
}
```